# elasticsearch scripting: how to access other buckets in histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch 2.3.3

I have *date_histogram* and inside it a [bucket_script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html). In the script, I want to use some aggregations on the current bucket (no problem there) but also an aggregation *on the previous bucket*. I did not see any way to access other buckets inside an script.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible?

Here is my query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://$ESHOST:$ESPORT/$INDEX_NAME/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "size": 0, 
    "aggs" : {
        "s_price" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "a_date",
                "interval" : "month",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "median_price": { "percentiles": { "field": "s_price", "percents": [50] } },
                "median_price_change": { "derivative": { "buckets_path": "median_price.50" }},
                "median_percent_change": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "gap_policy" : "insert_zeros",
                        "buckets_path": {
                          "price_change": "median_price_change",
                          "price_abs": "median_price.50"
                        },
                        "script": "price_change / price_abs * 100"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Instead of *price_abs* pointing to the current bucket value, I would like it to  point to the previous bucket value.

thanks

Comment: Please share what you have so far to better illustrate what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Val I added more details

Answer (score 0):

(Found this searching for the same problem. Its old, but haven't found the answer elsewhere so answering for others getting here by search)

You have what you need to calculate the previous value from the "derivative" aggregation:

```
"script": "price_change / (price_change - price_abs) * 100"
```

Serial differencing with a lag of 1 will get you there the same as derivative.